# Tizen: How to measure noise level?

Tags: tizen, noise, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, decibel

I would like to get a decibel level output from the built-in microphone of the Samsung Gear S3 and use it in my App. I want to measure the noise level in the device's environment. (Is it loud at the place, the watch is worn at?) How is this possible? Wearable or native does not matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check  audio_in_get_sample_rate  from https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MEDIA__AUDIO__IN__MODULE.html#ga95b1de7dc472ffe7db006fdc28f1b4e3. Also check relation https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node150.html

Comment: Thanks this advice, but I think this is not, what I meant. I want to measure the noise level in the device's environment. ( Is it loud at the place, the watch is worn at?)

Comment: you need to capture surroundings sound then measure its sample rate